# Is information sent over an http localhost connection secure?

Tags: flask

This might be a bit of a noob question, but anyway ... I am developing an app using Flask and Virtualenv. As I understand, the server running at  http://127.0.0.1:5000/ is not externally visible by default. I am assuming that this means that any information sent to the server (even though it is by an unencrypted http connection) is therefore secure. I can't seem to find much through Google that addresses this, so I just wanted to try to confirm that it is the case that all information sent to the localhost server is secure.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your localhost is secure i.e. not compromised and your local network configuration does not allow requests to your localhost's port 5000, then i'd recon it's pretty secure.